# ApplicationDbContext.EntityName() returning null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Why db.Countries() comes null in following scenario-
1. CityController

```
[Authorize]
public class CityController : Controller
{        
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext("CP");

    // GET: City/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.CountryId = new SelectList(db.Countries.ToList(), "CountryId", "Name");
        return View();
    }
```

2. ApplicationDbContext

   ```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
   {
       public ApplicationDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
       : base(nameOrConnectionString)
       {
       }

       internal IDbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }

       ...
   }
   ```
3. Country is defined as-

   ```
   [Table("Country")]
   public class Country
   {
       #region Fields
       private ICollection<City> _cities;
       #endregion

       #region Scalar Properties
       public Guid CountryId { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string CountryCode { get; set; }
       #endregion

       #region Navigation Properties
       public virtual ICollection<City> Cities
       {
           get { return _cities ?? (_cities = new List<City>()); }
           set { _cities = value; }
       }
       #endregion
    }
   ```
4. City is defined as-

   ```
   [Table("City")]
   public class City
   {
       #region Fields
       private ICollection<Location> _locations;
       #endregion

       #region Scalar Properties
       public Guid CityId { get; set; }
       public Guid CountryId { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string CityCode { get; set; }
       public string ZipCode { get; set; }
       public Country Country { get; set; }
       #endregion

       #region Navigation Properties
       public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations
       {
           get { return _locations ?? (_locations = new List<Location>()); }
           set { _locations = value; }
       }
       #endregion
   }
   ```

What could be the reason for not populating Country table records and returning countries to null?

Comment: Changing IDbSet to DbSet doesn't make any sense and even it doesn't resolve issue.

Answer (score 1):

After sparing few hours, I just noticed the Access-modifier of Countries properties which was internal. I made it Public and magic happened! It works though I don't have any explanation on WHY part of it.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }
    //internal IDbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
```

Thanks everyone.